# Can any one explain these c operators

Tags: c, operators

What is the function of these operators ( =& , ~ ), i found this code posted as a joke and titled

> "Found in early Unix sources:"

```
if(rp->p_flag & SSWAP) {
    rp->p_flag =& ~SSWAP;
    aretu(u.u_ssav);
}
```

EDIT:
Source: http://www.bsdlover.cn/study/UnixTree/V6/usr/sys/ken/slp.c.html

Comment: That's just a bit flipper, what's the joke?

Comment: see it from here http://www.bsdlover.cn/study/UnixTree/V6/usr/sys/ken/slp.c.html as i removed the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is [unary bitwise complement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50et82s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which flips the bits in an integer.

However, after reading a comment and realizing I read your code wrong, I realized that the code that you have presented won't even compile in a **modern** compiler.

Thanks to @Avi: the operator `=&` means what `&=` means today, but this syntax really predates current C standards so it is truly ancient UNIX code.

**What is would really mean today**

The `&` here should act as the `address-of` operator, and not the `bitwise AND` operator.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 2;
    x =& ~y;
}
```

Compiling this code would produce:

`error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

I really think there was a problem in transcription, as logically, it should be `&=` and not the other way.

In the case that it is actually `&=`, then it is doing a bitwise and.

Comment: But the example is `=&` not `&=`

Comment: In early C, the assignment operators had the operator on the right. So it was `=&` instead of `&=`, and `=+` instead of `+=`.

Comment: They changed it, because it was ambiguous - `x=-3` could mean `x = -3` or `decrement x by 3`.

Answer (score 6):

You young whippersnappers were born too late :)

This code comes from a very early version of Unix (pre V7). The joke is that the comment just above it is ["You are not supposed to understand this"](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/odd.html), which has become [a bit of a legend](http://minnie.tuhs.org/TUHS/Usenet/notunderstand.txt).

Comment: Both links are down since ~2014, archived links: https://web.archive.org/web/20141204124808/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/odd.html, https://web.archive.org/web/20120324034620/http://minnie.tuhs.org/TUHS/Usenet/notunderstand.txt
Another source on the legend: https://thenewstack.io/not-expected-understand-explainer/ + lecture on the details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HTS_MJ4C30

Answer (score 5):

In early C, the assignment operators had the operator on the right. So it was `=&` instead of `&=`, and `=+` instead of `+=`.

So this code just checks if a certain bit is set, and if so, takes action and turns off the bit.

Answer (score 3):

`=&` is actually two separate operators: `=` and `&`, so the line is equivalent to `rp->p_flag = & ~SSWAP;`.

`~` is the [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) operator, so `~SSWAP` will be result of flipping the bits of `SSWAP`. `& ~SSWAP` will result in the reference of the result of `~SSWAP`, which is a compile error. So the thing won't compile using a modern compiler (since C89), but `=&` is equivalent to `&=` on modern compilers.

`&=` applies the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) on `rp->p_flag` and `~SSWAP` and places the result in `rp->p_flag`. The end result is that all `0` bits in `SSWAP` will turn off the respective bits in `rp->p_flag` if they are set. This will only be executed if at least one `1` bit will be turned off, so as to only call `aretu(u.u_ssav)` if the value of `rp->p_flag` will change as a result of the operation.

Comment: Ehrm, actually when `&` comes directly after the `=`, it's used as an unary operator, so it's the address-of operator, *not* bitwise and. Of course taking the address of a temporary makes absolutely no sense, so it's somewhat obvious that this is a typo and `&=` (which is one operator) was meant.

Comment: @sepp2k It hit me just before I read your comment. If you don't mind, I'm going to incorporate this into my answer.

Comment: You may note that since C89 the operator =& doesn't exist anymore. Only the operator &= is valid. In earlier C compilers this was actually valid, so this is really from early UNIX source code.

Answer (score 2):

From the [horse's mouth](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html):

> B introduced generalized assignment
>   operators, using x=+y to add y to x.
>   The notation came from Algol 68
>   [Wijngaarden 75] via McIlroy, who had
>   incorporated it into his version of
>   TMG. (In B and early C, the operator
>   was spelled =+ instead of += ; this
>   mistake, repaired in 1976, was induced
>   by a seductively easy way of handling
>   the first form in B's lexical
>   analyzer.)